# 無念なり - what is なり?

Tags: grammar, spoken-language

I saw a cartoon character(平沢唯, 「けいおん！」, ep.2) use this exclamation: 「無念なり」 expressing her regret at the lack of money. I'd like to find a grammar point explaining the use of 「なり」 here. After some lookup on the Internet it seems that なり can also be written as 成り (so I take it it's a derivative of 成る). However, it appears that none of the grammar books I've searched gives an explanation to this specific use (everything I've found concerns only V + なり and doesn't make much sense in this context).
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A-as-an-archaic-to-be

Comment: Seems to be the case here, thanks! I also found this link that seems to reiterate what is said in it:
http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A